# How to install the package \usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,arrows.meta,backgrounds}?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, ubuntu

I used the line `\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,arrows.meta,backgrounds}` in my latex code to generate architecture diagram with arrows. But it shows error as

> Can't find file `\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,arrows.meta,backgrounds}...`

Due to this I can't generate my architecture diagram correctly. Please anyone help me to use the above package in my LaTeX code in Ubuntu 14.04.

My code is as below.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,arrows.meta,backgrounds}


\tikzset{
    module/.style={%
        draw, rounded corners,
        minimum width=#1,
        minimum height=7mm,
        font=\sffamily
        },
    module/.default=2cm,
    >=LaTeX
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % This will show the frame around the figure
    show background rectangle]

    % Place first 6 items
    \node[module] (I1) {Item-1};
    \node[module, below=of I1] (I2) {Item-2};
    \node[module, below=of I2] (I3) {Item-3};
    \node[module=1cm, below=8mm of I3] (I5) {Item-5};
    \node[module=1cm, left= 3mm of I5] (I4) {Item-4};
    \node[module=1cm, right= 3mm of I5] (I6) {Item-6};
    % Inner box around Items 3-6
    \node[fit=(I3) (I4) (I6), draw, inner sep=2mm] (fit3) {};
    % Outer box around all left items
    \node[fit=(fit3) (I1), draw, inner sep=2mm] (fit1) {};
    % Connections
    \foreach \i in {4,5,6}
        \draw[->] (I3)--(I\i);
    \draw[->] (I2)--(I1);
    \draw[->] (I2)--(fit3);

    % Items 7-8-9. Item 7 as label of Item-8
    \node[module, right=2cm of {I2-|fit1.east}, 
        label={[yshift=5mm, font=\sffamily]Item-7}] 
        (I8) {Item-8};
    \node[module, below=of I8] (I9) {Item-9};
    %outer box around items 8-9
    \node[fit={(I9) (I9|-fit1.south) (I9|-fit1.north)}, draw, inner xsep=5mm, inner ysep=-\pgflinewidth] (fit8) {};

    %arrow between boxes
    \draw[<->,dashed] (fit1)--(fit8);

    %upper label
    \path (fit1.north east)--node[above=3mm, font=\sffamily\bfseries] (arc) {Architecture} (fit8.north west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the error it shows?

Comment: Notice that, even if you download `tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex` and so on, and put them into the same directory as your tex file, it most likely won't work as these libraries load other stuff which you also may not have. Do you have a proper TeX installation?

Comment: Thanks for your response[albert,marmot] .. @ albert : Ther error is : Can't find file \usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,arrows.meta,backgrounds}... @marmot : I follow AskUbuntu installation guidelines for TexLive installation.. Thanks..

Comment: You should divide the `\usetikzlibrary{..}` command into 4 different ones, to see which one is failing. Like `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}\usetikzlibrary{fit}` etc.  Once you do that, it will be more clear where it fails. To know which package you are missing.

Comment: In any case, a full tikz installation should have all those packages. (I am using the 2017 TexLive installation, for example). So most likely, you don't have the whole distribution installed, and instead have a minimal distribution. Or, you are using an older distribution that doesn't have those packages.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your kind response.. I will install properly and make use of it.. thanks..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.